# How can i solve this issue through Sql Developer with Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12518, TNS: listener could not hand off client connection

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle and MySQL.  Which database are you actually using?  It appears that your connection information is incorrect.  It's hard for us to know what the connection information is supposed to be in your organization, though.

Comment: i used only oracle database. i give correct connection information but i get this error (ORA - 12518)

Comment: Can other people connect to the database?  Is the listener running?

Comment: This is a server resource and/or configuration issue. Your DBA will need to troubleshoot this. There is nothing you can do from the client-side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below mentioned steps:

1.Processes parameter and verified by the v$resource_limit view.

2.If you are using a shared server, you may increase the number of dispatchers.

3.Check the alert log for any possible errors.

4.Check the swap, memory usage of the OS.

5.Check the Sid name  of database

Action: Turn on listener tracing and re-execute the operation. Verify that the listener and database instances are properly configured for direct handoff.